# In GitLab repository, what member role can see the source code but not repo members?

Tags: git, permissions, gitlab

I created a private repository in GitLab containing my sample work. I want to share this repository with possible advisor professors.

What permission should I grant to them so that they can see the source code but not all the repository members (a few other possible advisors)? Does the developer permission work for that?

I tried the guest permission first, but it doesn't let them to see the source code. Besides the guest role, there are the reporter, developer, and maintainer roles respectively.

Comment: Refer: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#project-members-permissions

View project code: Guest users are able to perform this action on public and internal projects, but not private projects.

Comment: Exactly! The `guest` permission doesn't help when the project is private. It's like sending the project link to someone.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible... but only for a GitLab Ultimate instance, and only with [GitLab 15.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/02/22/gitlab-15-9-released/#key-features) (February 2023) or more:

> ### Users with the Guest role can view private repositories
>
> Users with the Guest role and an Ultimate license can now view private repository content if their administrator gives them permission.
>
> Administrators must create a new role through the API, and assign that role to users who the administrator wants to have view repository permissions. Previously, users with the Guest role could not view code in private projects, limiting their utility.

> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#custom-roles) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/20277).